# What determines a cameras max FPS for still images?

Tags: comparison, burst-mode, features, specification

For example: the Canon M5 can shoot stills at a maximum rate of 7 frames per second, and the M50 can reach 10 frames per second. EOS 1DX Mark II advertises max 14~16 FPS bursts.

What stipulates this limit in cameras? What does the M50 have that the M5 doesn't, that allows it to reach higher burst speeds?

Answer (score 1):

For mirrorless cameras like the Canon M5 and M50, it is the processing power and speed of the camera’s digital processor. The M50 has the newest Digic 8 processor while the M5 uses Digic 7.

For a DSLR camera, it is a combination of the digital processor and the physical limitations of the mechanical shutter and mirror systems.
(the 1DX Mark II also has dual processors)

Comment: Do not forget readout speed. Processor speed is nice, but if you can not get the megabytes of data out of the senor fast enough, that turns into the limit. Saying "A7R" here.